# How to scroll to top and load iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a gallery of images of some books I'm reviewing. When someone clicks on a book on the page, I have an iframe at the top where I've targeted my  attribute to load the review of the book.

```
<iframe height="300px" width="100%" src="" name="iframe_reviews"></iframe>

<li class="one_quarter"><a href="b_reviews/book4.html" target="iframe_reviews"><img src="b_reviews/images/book4.jpg"></a></li>
```

That code works fine. What I'm having trouble with is that I have several books on the page. That means you need to scroll down to see books and if you click on a book, it loads in the iframe, but you can't tell it has ... you're still stuck on the bottom of the page.

Is there any way to target _top after the link as been clicked so that the book review loads in the iframe and the page scrolls back to the top simultaneously? Thank you.

Comment: `window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })`
should do the work

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do what with a Javascript function and the DOM property 'scrollTop'. Just assign a Javascript function to the link (using the 'onClick' event, so the function is called when the link is clicked) that sets the property to 0 (document.body.scrollTop = 0).

HTML:

```
<a href="b_reviews/book4.html" target="iframe_reviews" onclick="scrollToTop()">...</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function scrollToTop() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

As an alternative, you can just assign an id to the tag and use the function getElementById.

HTML:

```
<a href="b_reviews/book4.html" target="iframe_reviews" id="book">...</a>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('book').onclick = function(){
   document.body.scrollTop = 0;
};
```